# Last rows of long table in landscape are not in landscape (lyx)

Tags: lyx, longtable, landscape

I have several child documents in which the long tables are properly displayed in landscape when I export each of them individually in pdf format. Nevertheless, when I compile the main document in which I have included the child documents, the last rows of each column are no longer part of the long table: they are not displayed in landscape mode (the page is now in vertical) and its content is cut as it obviously does not fit the margins. I made sure that both documents have the same margins and the same latex preamble set.

Any suggestions about how to overcome this issue when compiling the main document? Below I attach screenshots of the PDF in which the format of the multi-page tables can be better appreciated:

A) Screenshot of table in PDF from child document (table OK!):
[image]

B) Screenshot of table in PDF from main document (last rows are broken and are not anymore in landscape):
[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: that looks like a bug. But (naturally it can't be in my code:-)  can you post a generated latex document that shows this?

Comment: I generated a new main document and the table is properly generated even though it comes from a child document... I am still trying to debug what the issue with the other main document is... I think it might have some issues with in-line latex code that I added to customise the table of contents... I will keep looking for the error and edit the question if I find it!

Comment: that really shouldn't happen so if you suspect it is happening just with standard longtable and lscape code then if it is too big to post here you can always send to me, (you'll find my email easily enough)

Comment: It seems that using ```\let\clearpage\relax``` to remove a blank page that is generated before the table of contents causes a conflict with the longtable and lscape... I did not know that could happen. Now I have the blank page before ToC back, but my long tables look all fine! Will approach something different to get rid of this blank page...

Comment: `\let\clearpage\relax` completely breaks latex even without longtable. You are not guaranteed any output at all after that. Still it proves my first comment was correct:-)

Comment: If you think this is a LyX bug, it would be very helpful if you could make a bug report at https://www.lyx.org/trac and post a minimal example: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: It was not a LyX bug, I agree with David's comment above -- all fixed without adding ```let/clearpage/relax```. Thanks!!